# Different results for COUNT using as window function with and without ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Say, I have this simple table:

```sql
declare @t table ([period] date, [contract] int, price int);
insert into @t values
('2022-11-01', 1, 234),
('2022-12-01', 1, 277),
('2023-01-01', 1, 489),
('2022-11-01', 2, 187),
('2022-12-01', 2, 598),
('2022-03-01', 2, 478);
```

When using it as window function with and without `ORDER BY`, I get different results.
When I used `ORDER BY`, I was surprised with the results since I expected all values in `count` column to be `3`.

```sql
select     *,
       count = count(*) over (partition by [contract] order by [period])
from @t;
```

| period | contract | price | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | 1 | 234 | 1 |
| 2022-12-01 | 1 | 277 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 489 | 3 |
| 2022-11-01 | 2 | 478 | 1 |
| 2022-12-01 | 2 | 187 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2 | 598 | 3 |

I couldn't understand, why this was happening. Then I decided to remove `order by [period]` clause. And then all worked like a charm!

```sql
select     *,
       count = count(*) over (partition by [contract])
from @t;
```

| period | contract | price | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | 1 | 234 | 3 |
| 2022-12-01 | 1 | 277 | 3 |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 489 | 3 |
| 2022-11-01 | 2 | 478 | 3 |
| 2022-12-01 | 2 | 187 | 3 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2 | 598 | 3 |

After that I decided to take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#over---partition_by_clause---order_by_clause---row_or_range_clause--), and it says:

> The *order_by_clause* determines the logical order of the operation. See [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) clause (Transact-SQL) for more information.

And *that* `OVER` link says:

> `ROWS/RANGE` that limits the rows within the partition by specifying start and end points within the partition. **It requires ORDER BY argument and the default value is from the start of partition to the current element if the ORDER BY argument is specified.**

Do I correctly understand that as soon as I specify `ORDER BY`, it acts like `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`? Then when I omit it, why it acts as `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`?

Comment: Almost. For when an `ORDER BY` is specified it defaults to `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.  The `RANGE` is important, as `ROWS` and `RANGE` do act differently (sometimes just in the underlying processing others in results too).

Comment: Because ORDERBY clause calculated the count differently https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#order-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#order-by) is quite clear on this further down the same page.

> **ORDER BY**
>
> ```sql
> ORDER BY *order_by_expression* [COLLATE *collation_name*] [ASC|DESC]
> ```
>
> Defines the logical order of the rows within each partition of the result set. That is, it specifies the logical order in which the window function calculation is performed.
>
> - If it is not specified, the default order is ASC and **window function will use all rows in partition**.
> - **If it is specified, and a `ROWS`/`RANGE` is not specified, then default `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is used as default** for window frame by the functions that can accept optional `ROWS`/`RANGE` specification (for example min or max).

So by default you get a running sum. This default is **only** if you specify `ORDER BY`, otherwise the window calculation is over the whole partition (ie not running).

Note that `ROWS` and `RANGE` are subtly different, and annoyingly 99% of the time you want `ROWS` for a running sum so make sure to specify it.